# How to get the "x" element in React JS while using the map object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array with objects I am using `map` to render the elements on the page, The problem is that I want to get the last object from the array (in my case it is 'documents') and set a class for it to style it, you can also see my [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-http-lrfxf)

```
export default function Nav() {
  const [navItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Home",
      link: "/dashboard"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Investments",
      link: "/investments"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Organize",
      link: "/organize"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Documents",
      link: "/documents"
    }
  ]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {navItems.map((i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i.id}>
            <p>{i.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the index of the item while mapping through it. And check if the `index` is equal to the `navItems.length - 1`. Check this-

```
<div className="App">
  {navItems.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div
       key={item.id}
       className={index === navItems.length - 1 ? 'your-desired-class': ''}>
          <p>{item.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```